# if-else not functioning

Tags: python

Here are some results:

[image: screenshot of results]

Wondering why my code won't work. As you can see at the bottom, it does function (to a certain extent). My best estimate is that my logic is not sufficient for the task at hand. Please be patient with me because I'm new to this.

Here is my code:

```
user_input_change = int(input('Enter Integer: '))
if user_input_change >= 0:
    if user_input_change >= 100:
        if (user_input_change // 100) != 0:
            if (user_input_change // 100) > 1:
                print('{} Dollar(s)'.format(user_input_change // 100))
                user_input_change = (user_input_change % 100)
        else:
            user_input_change = (user_input_change % 100)
    if user_input_change < 100:
        if (user_input_change // 25) != 0:
            if (user_input_change // 25) > 1:
                print('{} Quarter(s)'.format(user_input_change // 25))
                user_input_change = (user_input_change % 25)
        else:
            user_input_change = (user_input_change % 25)
    if user_input_change <= 25:
        if (user_input_change // 10) != 0:
            if (user_input_change // 10) > 1:
                print('{} Dime(s)'.format(user_input_change // 10))
                user_input_change = (user_input_change % 10)
        else:
            user_input_change = (user_input_change % 10)
    if user_input_change <= 10:
        if (user_input_change // 5) != 0:
            if (user_input_change // 5) > 1:
                print('{} Nickel(s)'.format(user_input_change // 5))
                user_input_change = (user_input_change % 5)
        else:
            user_input_change = (user_input_change % 5)
    if user_input_change <= 5:
        if (user_input_change // 1) != 0:
            if (user_input_change // 1) > 1:
                print('{} Pennies'.format(user_input_change // 1))
            else:
                print('{} Penny'.format(user_input_change // 1))
else:
    print('No change')
```

Comment: "My best estimate is that my logic is not sufficient for the task at hand" It would help if you tell us what the code is supposed to do. Right now we only see what it _is_ doing, which is apparently not the right thing.

Comment: Looks overly complicated but I don't see anything obviously incorrect at first glance.  What's an example of input you provide it that doesn't have the result you expect?

Comment: Start by avoiding unnecessary indentation. Replace the outer `if` statement with `if user _input_change < 0: print("No change"); sys.exit()`; then the rest of the `else` clause can be executed unconditionally.

Comment: This one is probably one you've already seen, but bear with me; it's for figuring out precise change. For instance, if I input 100, I would receive 1 dollar, and if I input 230, I would receive "2 Dollar(s), 3 Dime" (s)...

Comment: you can change `if (user_input_change // 5) != 0: if (user_input_change // 5) > 1:` to just one statement. also, you have no need to check if the user input is greater than 100, then 25, then 10, etc, because it would be zero anyways. What you should do instead is just save each modulo value to a list or variable. Then, print out a formatted version of the nonzero values.

Comment: Paste the text of the results not  a link to an image.  Images can be read by screen readers and nobody wants to click on outside links.

Comment: Expanding on Mark Tolonen's comment, see "[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527)"

Comment: [Code samples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article.

Comment: "[doesn't work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/133817)" contains no useful information, as it states neither what should happen, nor what actually happens, and asking here on SO generally implies you've got non-working code. Please explain the expected/desired results/behaviors, along with the actual. [That might be why](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) some folks [downvoted](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: Asking about [homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527) on SO has extra considerations, and special guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you check `if (user_input_change // 25) > 1:` and similar. Let's look at the different `if` statements (for the second coin, but it applies to all coins):

- `if user_input_change < 100:` this check is redundant; after the previous block, the value has to be `< 100`
- `if (user_input_change // 25) != 0:` this is just a complicated way to say `user_input_change >= 25`
- `if (user_input_change // 25) > 1:` accordingly, this means `user_input_change >= 50`, so if the value is between 25 and 50, you just do `% 25` in the else, but never print the coin.

Long story short: You have way too many nested `if` statements. The following is enough:

```
user_input_change = int(input('Enter Integer: '))
if user_input_change > 0:
    if user_input_change >= 100:
        print('{} Dollar(s)'.format(user_input_change // 100))
        user_input_change = (user_input_change % 100)
    if user_input_change >= 25:
        print('{} Quarter(s)'.format(user_input_change // 25))
        user_input_change = (user_input_change % 25)
    if user_input_change >= 10:
        print('{} Dime(s)'.format(user_input_change // 10))
        user_input_change = (user_input_change % 10)
    if user_input_change >= 5:
        print('{} Nickel(s)'.format(user_input_change // 5))
        user_input_change = (user_input_change % 5)
    if user_input_change >= 1:
        print('{} Pennies'.format(user_input_change // 1))
else:
    print('No change')
```

Also, this can be shortened using a `dict`, or `list` of `tuple`, with the different values and coin names. You may also try `divmod` here:

```
coins = {100: "Dollar(s)", 25: "Quarter(s)", 10: "Dime(s)", 5: "Nickel(s)", 1: "Pennie(s)"}
user_input_change = int(input('Enter Integer: '))
if user_input_change > 0:
    for val, name in coins.items():
        amount, user_input_change = divmod(user_input_change, val)
        if amount > 0:
            print(f'{amount} {name}')
else:
    print('No change')
```

Comment: While I quite like this answer, the original question seems like a homework question so I'm hoping they don't just copy your code for their assignment...

Comment: This is undoubtedly homework. I'm still learning, but since online learning is challenging, I occasionally need to go to my community to get comments on my faulty code. You've been there before, so don't lie to me. Thank you, but, since I was unsure of where in my code the remaining amount wasn't being dumped into the subsequent coin. As you can probably see, I grasp the idea, but I could need some feedback now and again. I don't plagiarize, I always add my own touch to it.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things can be improved in your code.

- The first `if` condition here is made redundant by the second (1 is bigger than 0).

  ```
   if (user_input_change // 1) != 0:
       if (user_input_change // 1) > 1:
  ```

  So you can instead do

  ```
   if (user_input_change // 1) > 1:
  ```
- Adding redundant `user_input_change = (user_input_change % 5)` statements.
- Dividing by 1 for the pennies.
- Using `"{}".format()` instead of f-strings, likeso `f"{}"`
- You may also use the shorthand assignment operator, e.g. in your case `user_input_change = user_input_change % 1` becomes `user_input_change %= 1`

With all that in mind, here is a working version of your code.

```
change = int(input('Enter Integer: '))
    
if change > 0:
    if change >= 100:
        print(f"{change//100} Dollar(s)")
        change %= 100
    if change >= 25:
        print(f"{change//25} Quarter(s)")
        change %= 25
    if change >= 10: 
        print(f"{change//10} Dime(s)")
        change %= 10
    if change >= 5:
        print(f"{change//5} Nickel(s)")
        change %= 5
    if change > 1:
        print(f"{change} Pennies")
    else:
        print("1 Penny")
else:
    print("No change")
```

Comment: Seeing that tobias has answered your question much more succinctly, I'd rather you refer to their solution.